# Magento 2.2.1 Readiness Check, Cron Scripts, Cloudways

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento2, cloudways

I have installed Magento 2.2.1 on my Cloudways server. While trying to install an extension in the extension manager. This is what I get

Cron script readiness check failed.

Error from Setup Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet

[image]

I have ssh into server and installed a crontab using this guide http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron . The problem is still there. I need help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Cloudways support and they helped with it, the problem was caching.

Answer (score 1):

Readiness check depends on the Magento crons

Set cron job like this:

```
*/5 * * * * php -c /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini /var/www/html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v “Ran jobs by schedule” >> /var/www/html/var/log/magento.cron.log

*/5 * * * * php -c /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini /var/www/html/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/var/log/update.cron.log

*/5 * * * * php -c /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >>/var/www/html/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Increase memory_limit

Remove `.setup_cronjob_status` and `.update_cronjob_status` file from your webroot directory for example `/var/www/html/var/`

Clear all cache"magento cache (`bin/magento cache:clean` and `bin/magento cache:flush`) and in case of varnish purge varnish cache too" and restart fpm/apache service.